# Is there a way in C# to replicate a '#ifndef _DEBUG' from C/C++?

Tags: c#, debugging, programming-languages

I'd like to conditionally exclude/include code based on whether I'm building in **debug mode**.

Can I use something as simple as a `#ifndef _DEBUG` as I would in C++?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#endif

#if !DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("NOT Debug version");
#endif
```

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if).

Comment: ... and consider using Trace/Debug output respectively before rolling your own. Same goes for assertions.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815788/how-to-trace-and-debug-in-visual-c

Answer (score 5):

```
#if !DEBUG
     // whatever
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use preprocessors in C#.

Here is a list from msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Note: that you can also define your own on the "Build" tab of your project properties (you can even set up custom Configurations in the Configurations Manager, each of which defines different custom preprocessors, so turning them off and on is as easy as clicking on the drop down menu).

Comment: The link is no longer working. That is why answering with link to external site is not so good.